# Fire JavaScript event after synchronous Form POST?

Tags: javascript, php, post

OK, so I *think* there isn't a way to do this, without using an iframe, or submitting my form via an ajax call, but anyways, I figured I'd ask.

Let's say I have a web server with the following config

```
public/
├── file.php
├── index.php
└── myfile.csv
```

On `index.php` I have a form. It is a **POST** form that has an action of `file.php`. Attached to that form is a JS event handler to insert some "*Loading...*" text into the DOM when it is submitted.

#### index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>

  <h1>Reports</h1>
  <form action="file.php" id="my-form" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Generate and Download File" id="submit-button">
  </form>

  <div id="result"></div>

  <script>
    function addEventListener(el, eventName, handler) {
      if (el.addEventListener) {
        el.addEventListener(eventName, handler);
      } else {
        el.attachEvent('on' + eventName, function(){
          handler.call(el);
        });
      }
    }

    var form = document.getElementById('my-form');

    // On form submit, display a Loading... message
    addEventListener(form, 'submit', function() {
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<h3>Loading...</h3>';
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Pretty simple. Now, `file.php`, imagine this is doing some heavy computations, and when it is done, it generates a .CSV file and serves it up for download.

Here is a sample that emulates what my script is doing:

#### file.php

```
<?php
// Dummy file
$file = 'myfile.csv';

// Simulate heavy calculations...
sleep(3);

if (file_exists($file)) {
    // Download the file
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

For completeness, here is `myfile.csv`:

#### myfile.csv

```
Hello,World
```

Now, here is my question:

After my file is served up, and the download starts, can I remove the "Loading..." text I inserted into the DOM?

Is there a JS event that can fire after a synchronous form gets POSTed?

Like I said, I don't think there is but I wanted to check around.

Comment: `"I think there isn't a way to do this, without using an iframe,"` Correct - an iframe is currently the best solution, and very simple. Jusr create a hidden iframe, set the forms action as said iframe. Attach 2 js functions - one to the forms submit event, which displays a loading div, one the the iframe onload event, which hides it

Comment: Thanks @Steve. I think you are correct, and your suggestion makes perfect sense. Just wanted to double check that there wasn't something obvious I was missing.

Answer (score -1):

What it seems like you are doing here is using the browsers "cache" to continue showing the page even though the browser has requested a different page which returned a file and not HTML to be interpretted.

In my Experience we used jquery Ajax to show/hide a "Loading" DIV.

(Scroll down for non-ajax solution)

```
$.ajax({
    url: script_url,
    cache: false,
    async: sync_type,
    type: "POST",
    data: form_data,
    dataType: "html",
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings)
    {
        //BUILD LOADING HTML
        loading_html = '<div class="ajax-loading">&nbsp;</div>';

        //SHOW LOADING
        switch(return_mode)
        {
            case 'append':
                $('#'+container_id).addClass('ajax-loading');
            break;

            case 'prepend':
                $('#'+container_id).addClass('ajax-loading');
            break;

            default:
                $('#'+container_id).html(loading_html);
            break;
        }//END SWITCH RETURN MODE

    },//END FUNCTION BEFORESEND
    success: function(html_returned, success_code, jqXHR_object) 
    {
        switch(return_mode)
        {
            case 'append':
                //APPEND HTML RESPONSE
                $('#'+container_id).append(html_returned);

            break;

            case 'prepend':
                $('#'+container_id).prepend(html_returned);

            break;

            default:
                //REPLACE CONTAINER CONTENTS WITH HTML RESPONSE
                $('#'+container_id).html(html_returned);

            break;
        }//END SWITCH RETURN MODE

    },//END FUNCTION SUCCESS
    error: function(jqXHR, exception) 
    {

        //SHOW ERRORS 
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) 
        {
            //alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) 
        {
            //alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) 
        {
            //alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') 
        {
            //alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
        } else if (exception === 'timeout') 
        {
            //alert('Time out error.');
        } else if (exception === 'abort') 
        {
            //alert('Ajax request aborted.');
        } else {
            //alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
        }//END IF JQXHR.STATUS === 0
    },//END FUNCTION ERROR
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus)
    {
        //REMOVE LOADING CLASS
        $('#'+container_id).removeClass('ajax-loading');

    }
```

});

ALL of that being said, if you really cant use a jquery ajax call, then you may try looking at tricking the page with some CSS.  For example have a `<div id="loading_div" class="loading" style="display: none"></div>` which displays your loading details (spinners, etc.)

When they click to submit your form then display the loading DIV.

```
getElementById('loading_div').css("display", "block");
```

Then at the bottom of your page, have a javascript section which states:

```
<script>
//HIDE THE LOADING DIV
getElementById('loading_div').css("display", "none");
</script>
```

If your file.php script redirects the browers back to your page:

```
header("Location: my_page_url.php");
```

Then they will see this loading div until the file is handled out, then the page with reload (but the download dialog will remain)

Comment: The OP is attempting to initiate a file download, this will not work over ajax, nor can a file mime type header and a redirect header be sent at the same time